# Include files in Maven JAR package

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project with the following structure:

```
project

-src
--main
---java
----(All my .java files are here in their packages)
---resource
----(All my resources are here)

-database (HSQLDB files)
--db.script
--db.properties
--db.data

-target
--Maven build directory

pom.xml
```

I want the maven jar plugin to package in the database folder when it builds a JAR file. I've tried including as outlined here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html, but it doesn't find the directory "../database" (or ../../database OR ../../../database!), and also it now doesn't include any of the classes or resources (It was including them before).

So what should I have in the configuration of the maven jar plugin?
Which is the correct path to include and how do I keep the files it was including before?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, only resources located in `src/main/resources` are added in the JAR.
What you tried to do by configuring the `maven-jar-plugin` defines only the filetset to exclude or include in the built JAR.
But these files still have to be located in a resources folder where Maven looks for resources.

So, you have two ways to solve your requirement:

- move `database`  in the standard directory : `src/main/resources`.
- specifies two `resource` folders for resources :

[To do the latter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html), in the pom.xml add in the `build` tag :

```
<resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>          
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>database-resources</directory>
     </resource>
</resources>
```

Then add the `database` folder that you want package inside the `database-resources`.

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way to keep it inside a folder?

Comment: See this is the weird thing is in connecting to HSQLDB I need to specify a filepath absolutely from the project folder. Which is annoying. So the folder structure of the database needs to remain when packaged in the JAR.

Comment: "See this is the weird thing is in connecting to HSQLDB I need to specify a filepath absolutely from the project folder." It feels like a thing to improve. Placing the folder at this place is possible with Maven but it is not a standard way and also is tricky. One advise : try to solve this location issue as you connect to HSQLDB. If  you don't manage, ask a new question on SO.

Comment: And there's definitely no way to add from the root directory?

Comment: I don't advise it but you may with the `copy-resources` goal. Look at : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html